# Wordpress bootstrap collapse menu not showing links

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Im working on a wordpress theme made with bootstrap. I currently have a collapsible navigation bar, and the links populate and work when not collapsed. But when I change the resolution and the button appears, you can click but the links won't show up.

Here is my navbar placed in header.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>      
             <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'themeslug_logo' ) ) : ?>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href='<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>' title='<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>' rel='home'><img src='<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'themeslug_logo' ) ); ?>' alt='<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>'></a>
              <?php else : ?>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href='<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>' title='<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>' rel='home'><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <?php  /* menu */
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary-menu',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            ); 
            ?>
</ul>
            </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the output HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse in" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="height: auto;">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
<ul id="menu-navigation" class="nav navbar-nav">
<li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22">
<a title="Blog" href="http://dillonraphael.com/blog/">Blog</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have the bootstrap.js or the bootstrap javascript files included/called on the bottom of the page? If not the button won't do anything.

Comment: @Braunson The button works. I press it and the white box expands. But there are no links inside. When the site uses the larger screen dimensions the links show on the actual navbar

Comment: Can grab the output of WordPress and post it?

Comment: @Braunson posted. so the actual link is being outputted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is incorrect, it has two div's with navbar-collapse

Take the WordPress wp_nav_menu function and remove the div's and ul wrapped around it since it generates it's own and you have the correct class specified.

**Remove this and it's closing tags**:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

**Then add this to your array**

```
container_id => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
```